# Rails SQLite3 Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

This is driving me crazy. When I try to do anything (generate a controller, install Active Admin, etc.) I am flooded by errors regarding sqlite3. Here is a bit of the error messages:

```
/Users/ed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in     `require': incompatible library version - /Users/ed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle (LoadError)
from /Users/ed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from /Users/ed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Whenever errors show up you should go from the first error to the last. Meaning: Here it is telling you that sqlite is incompatible. You should check your gem file and maybe use a newer version (or an older one, if that fixes some errors). After you change the gem file, do `bundle install` and then restart your server.

Comment: I fixed the errors by adding the 'inherited_resource' gem  to activeadmin.